# How to make fullpage.js responsive with concrete5 5.7 CMS?

Tags: fullpage.js, concrete5, responsive

I need some help with my web site. I'm using the plugin fullpage.js,but when I tried it on the mobile the web page is not responsive. I also have another page in the website that does not use the plugin, and it is responsive. So I think I have well declare the framework bootstrap.
I don't know where to look at, I'm really mad with this issue because I have spend a lot of time to make it beautiful if I can say.
May be showing my page_theme will help :

```
namespace Application\Theme\Elegant;

use Concrete\Core\Page\Theme\Theme;

class PageTheme extends Theme{

protected $pThemeGridFrameworkHandle='bootstrap3';

public function registerAssets(){
  $this->providesAsset('javascript', 'bootstrap/*');
  $this->providesAsset('css', 'bootstrap/*');
  $this->providesAsset('css', 'blocks/form');
  $this->providesAsset('css', 'core/frontend/*');
  $this->requireAsset('javascript', 'jquery');
}
```

I don't want to change from concrete to wordpress, I really enjoy concrete5, and I want to learn, solving that problem. 
I thought about using the media queries, but it's been 3 days working on it and I do not see the end. Even when I finally finished the media queries for smart phone, unfortunately I find that I now had to do it for landscape mode, and for each category of large screen size. So I thought that someone more experienced might could help me. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are you already using the `responsiveHeight` or `responsiveWidth` options of fullpage.js to turn autoScrolling off in fullpage.js?

Comment: Hello Alvaro. I do not think it is a problem with your fantastic plugin. But my lack of experience with concrete5 CMS.
What I found as trick is to put the media queries in my initialization js file to activate fitToSection option that cancels the horizontal slides when the responsiveWidth desactivate the autoScrolling. That will save me some time to correctly position the element of my page.

Thanks you for reading me.